# How to duplicate a cloudera impala table backed by avro?

Tags: impala

I have a table "test" that I want to duplicate/copy into another table "test_copy". The "test1" table is backed by Avro, which prevents me from doing the following:

```
CREATE TABLE test_copy LIKE test"
INSERT INTO TABLE test_copy SELECT * FROM test
```

I can create the table LIKE test, but I am unable to insert records into the table.

```
ERROR: IllegalStateException: Unsupported TableSink format AVRO
```

I do not care about the avro, all I want is to be able to have a duplicate table and being able to query the records.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`. This will create a new table containing the results of the `SELECT` query. Unless you also specify `STORED AS [format]`, the new table will be stored in text files which is the default file format.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_copy AS SELECT * FROM test1;
```

See the [CREATE TABLE documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh5/latest/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_create_table.html) for more details about the `CREATE TABLE` DDL statement.